# Использую Ларавел 5,5, когда выставляю в finishsave метод numbers, id увеличавается на один больше при каждом обновление

Tags: php, laravel5

Использую Ларавел 5,5, когда выставляю в finishsave метод numbers, id увеличавается на один больше при каждом обновление, подскажите пожалуйста что за магия?

```
protected function finishSave(array $options)
{
    $this->numbers();
    Cache::tags([config('app.env') . '_responsecache'])->flush();
    parent::finishSave($options);
}
```

Class PhoneNumber и его метод:

```
 public function numbers()
        {
            dd($this->prefix_id);// увеличивается на один больше, но в базе нет такой ID, каждый раз при обновление
$data['numbers'] =
            DB::table('booking_phone_number')
                ->select(['booking_phone_number.id', DB::raw('concat(pp.prefix, booking_phone_number.number) as number')])
                ->join('booking_phone_prefix as pp', 'booking_phone_number.prefix_id', '=', 'pp.id')
                ->where('pp.region_id', $this->phonePrefix->region_id)
                ->where('booking_phone_number.category_id', $this->category_id)->get();
        }
```

я питаюсь получить из базы все номера с одиноковым префиксом и его категории в формате json и его переобразовать в файл чтобы найти в фронте было удобно, каждом изменение и добавление файл изменится (хотелось это сделать) например, префикс айди 1 и 4 номера в базе есть(с такой айди) и с префикс айди 2 и 3 номера в базе есть(с такой айди), но я сначала хотел получить все префиксы но он у меня увеличивается каким то образом, как можно это решить?

Comment: По идее метод [`finishSave`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_finishSave) должен срабатывать после сохранения модели в БД. Следовательно `id`-шка увеличивается таки на единичку.

Comment: Этот метод вызывается после [`save`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/85b2a5218088b0f60bf6e8c3a62891ba275a7269/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L521). Там и надо копать, вверх по цепочке событий. Точнее сказать к истокам вниз.

Comment: я изменяю бладе файл и сохраняю, после этого выходит проверяю префикс_айди он не должен увеличится, в базе только 1 и 2, а он куда увеличивается я вот не понимаю, странно

Comment: Но для таких дел лучше использовать События и Слушателей событий https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

Comment: Например в контроллере есть метод update, вам код нужен в этом модели?

Comment: я испраил код модели метода numbers, при этом не получаю нужную дату, то есть он возвращает только один номер, в базе 4 номера с таким префикс_айди

Comment: Код нужен в вопросе, где вы вызываете этот метод `finishSave`, хоть какое-то описание связей таблиц и что вообще вы в итоге пытаетесь получить.

Comment: исправил шапку, что еще могу добавить скажите думаю теперь более ясно написал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправил, оказывается блайд файле была ошибка исправил вновь сработала, спасибо всем кто соучаствовал,
во blade файле код был такой:

```
<div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('region_id', 'Регион:', ['class' => 'text-semibold']) !!}
        {!! Form::select('region_id', $regions, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

я поменял на это:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('region_id', 'Регион:', ['class' => 'text-semibold']) !!}
    {!! Form::select('region_id', $regions, isset($phoneNumber) ? $phoneNumber->phonePrefix->region_id : null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```